# hide drop down menu after clicking doesn't show it after rehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my menu items don't redirect to another page, so after clicking them they don't hide. I can hide them using javascript or jquery, but they hide forever. I've tried every single suggestion out there but none of them work for me. this is my html:

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="windows"><a href="#">Windows</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="tile">Tile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="closeAll">Close all</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

my css:

```
     nav ul ul {
       display: none;
       position: absolute;
       top: 100%;
       z-index: 1003;
     }

     nav ul li:hover > ul {
       display: block;
       height: auto;
     }
```

and my javascript for tile:

```
    tileObject = $('a.tile');
    tileObject.click(function () {
      $('.windows ul').hide();
      tileAction();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hide your menu using `$('.windows ul').hide();` you will need to do a `$('.windows ul').show();`(or smething equivalent) to display it again.

As `$('.windows ul')` will be hidden. You will need do bind the event to another element, for example

```
$('li.windows').click(function(){
    $('.windows ul').show()
});`
```

--EDIT--

For that effect you don't need javascript. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/d6djgmyc/). Just use the selector `:hover`. Then, if you want to do some actions using JS, just use the `hover` event. Take a look to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

--EDIT 2--

I got it now. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/d6djgmyc/4/). You need to unbind the hover event just before hide the element. Then after you hide the element you bind it again.

Comment: the problem is I want it to show on hover, not click. and if I show it on hover using javascript, it will always show because after I click tile the hover element will still be active.

Comment: your fiddle is what I have right now. the problem is that I want the drop down menu to hide after an item in it is clicked, but then show again when someone hovers on the menu.

Comment: Updated for second time, hope this help. Let me know the results.

Comment: this is working in the fiddle but for some reason in my code it disappears but appears and stays appeared forever. It's an issue on my side so I'll fix it. thanks for all your help, this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a.tile").click(function(){
        $("body").off("hover", "li.windows");
        $("nav ul li ul").hide();
        $("li.windows").hover(function(){
            $("nav ul li ul").show();
        });
    });


});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/kLbqw149/)

Answer (score -1):

If you HIDE and element then you need to SHOW it back again. First of all you have `top:100%` in your css and you dont need this.

Comment: but where do I show it? if I show it on hover, it will never hide in the first place. I don't want to show it on click since it is a drop down menu that should be showing on hover.